# PDO lastInsertId(); issue php

Tags: php, pdo

I have a database with a parent child relationship. I need to first insert into the parent table then get the ID, that I would use to then insert data into the child table.

The following is snippets of the code I am using to insert into the database. This is my first time using PDO class. The errors I am getting; Undefined property: **and** Call to a member function lastInsertId() on a non-object  database::$db. I must admit am I fairly new to PHP. Thank you

---

```
{

    public function __construct($DB_TYPE, $DB_HOST, $DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS)
    {
        parent::__construct($DB_TYPE.':host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
}
```

---

```
$this->db = new database(DB_TYPE, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

---

```
    $this->db->insert('images', array(
        'image_userID' => $data['image_userID'],
        'image_date' => $data['image_date']
    ));
```

---

```
/**
 * insert
 * @param string $table A name of table to insert into
 * @param string $data An associative array
 */
public function insert($table, $data)
{
    $fieldNames = implode('`, `', array_keys($data));
    $fieldValues = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($data));

    $sth = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (`$fieldNames`) VALUES ($fieldValues)");

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $sth->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    }

    $sth->execute();

$result= $this->db->lastInsertId();
 return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last insert ID comes from the *active statement*, and not from the database handle. So change the last line of your code to this:

```
$return = $sth->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response, I got lastInsertID() working, and looked into the two other issues you spoke about, I removed the semicolon, you where right there, but if I remove the backtick from fieldname my function no longer inserts.

Comment: As you can see I removed the part of the binding. Looked over it. As for the backtick, I see that in the implode also backticks are added, so the backticks in the query are allright. To early at the day and not enough coffee. Sorry for that.

Comment: This answer is not true. The lastInsertId comes from the PDO object, not the statement. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: agreed with @jsgoupil, this can not be valid, sth returns PDOStatement which does not hold lastInsertId, so I do not get how can this be correct answer. As I can see this can be an obsolete answer.